# ComponentOne Flex Grid Installation Issue in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, componentone

Hello,

I am using  **Windows 7 Ultimate Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate , Sql Server 2008 R2.**

I have a project solution that needs a 3rd party control - ComponentOne FlexGrid (.net2.5). The Project ran without problems on Windows XP, Visual studio 2008.

I tried to migrate to **Windows 7 Ultimate Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate**, however the setup for ComponetOne FlexGrid (.net2.5) failed

what should I do ?

Comment: do you use 64 bit now ? what does the setup-log-file say ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate works on .net framework 4.0. You should use C1StudioASPNET_2011v1.

That is the compatible version which can be downloaded from http://www.componentone.com/.
For any issue or discussion the forum is http://our.componentone.com/groups/